# Android wireless in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android, ics

I downloaded android-x86-4.0-RC1-asus_laptop.iso from http://www.android-x86.org/download and installed it in a VirtualBox virtual machine.

It all seems to work, but I can't seem to get the wireless to work.  The desktop hosting the guest android installation has a wireless internet connection.

Anyone know how I can get the wireless within the guest os to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android x86 on VirtualBox, the eeepc iso should used as mentioned on [their site.](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto)
Make sure you setup everything as specified on the website. Also when you run Android x86 with eeepc iso, The internet is connected but **Wireless is not connected**, Under android, if will show that wifi is not available/disconnected (Depends on hardware config).

And also Android 4.0 as x86 is just in RC, **it have some problems**. Try using Android 2.3 as x86 for the best experience. Still you can use Android 4.0, if you want to just try it.